Embedded stack error when deploying nested stacks
i am creating a simple trial to test the nested stacks.
i have 3 files [main file. test1, test2], test1 and test2 each file creating s3 bucket and managing them from the main file.
i uploaded the files to s3 bucket and updated the main file then upload the files again, when deploying the main file to cloudformation, "Embedded stack was not successfully created"
Note:

i have admin permission

Main file


Resources:
Test1Export:
Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
Properties:
TemplateURL: template-url
Test2Import:
Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
Properties:
TemplateURL: template-url

Test1 file

Resources:
WebS3Bucket1:
Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
Properties:
BucketName: test-1

Test2 file

Resources:
WebS3Bucket2:
Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
Properties:
BucketName: test-2
